# How to integrate payUmoney with opencart.?

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed payUmoney kit in opencart. But after configuring payUmoney as per instruction I am getting an error like:  **Sorry, Some Problem Occurred**.

Please suggest in solution to this problem and i am attaching an configuration screenshot of page.

Thanks in advance.[image: This error will come when i confirm order.]

[image: this image will with setting of payUmoney.]

Answer (score 3):

Test key and Salt have been changed. Try with below

**Test key**  : OygoFs

**Test Salt** : BV1QBwCv

Answer (score 1):

In order to test the gateway using a test key and salt, kindly follow these steps:

1 - Go on test.payumoney.com
2 - Sign up as a merchant - use any of your valid email ids - kindly do not use a random email id.
3 - Complete the "Business Details" - you may use PAN no. ABCDE1234F and DOB - 01/04/1990
4 - Complete "Bank Account Details" (You may use IFSC- ALLA0212632)
5 - Go to below mentioned location to get the Test Merchant Id : Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Profile Settings

After that send your test merchant id to technical team and they will approve it so that you can find your test key and salt at : Seller Dashboard -> Settings -> My account -> Merchant Key - Salt.

Comment: I have already do this procedure. Please suggest another solution.

Comment: Have you got salt key from payumoney?

Comment: I have used Mode:demo, so don't need of salt key. they provided test salt key that salt key i had used.

Comment: I know that you use demo mode but you have to follow this steps and after that paumoney provide salt key. if you use detail as per your describe figure that's not work for demo mode.

Comment: I have sign up but my salt key not generated.

Comment: I want to just test my website payment gateway is working or not. After completion I want buy some standard gateway.

Comment: Still my account is not approved.

Comment: send your merchant id to technical team of payumoney. they will approve your account after getting merchant id.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that Mode selected is `demo`. Check your Payu Money Account is also in `Test` mode. Otherwise change both to `Live / Production`

Comment: This must be posted as a comment.